# MySQLi warning with php7

Tags: php, ubuntu, mysqli

I'm getting the following errors from php7 on a new Ubuntu server:

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **~/tLogServ.php** on line **14**
>   
>   **Warning**:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in **~/tLogServ.php** on line **17**
>   
>   **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in ~/tLogServ.php:18
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}thrown in **~/tLogServ.php** on line **18**

Here's the tLogServ.php

```
    <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    $request = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
    $variable = $request->data;
     // echo($variable);
     $result = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM login where userID LIKE          'technician'");
   $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $passHashed = $rows['password'];

   if(password_verify($variable, $passHashed)){
    $loginMess = "success";
   }else{
    $loginMess = "fail";
   }

   echo json_encode($loginMess);

   $conn->close();
  ?>
```

and my connection script

```
<?php
DEFINE ('user', '$%^*(');
DEFINE ('pass', '^*&%*');
DEFINE ('host', '1*&^*&^');
DEFINE ('DB', '^*%*(&%^');
$conn = new mysqli(host, user, pass, DB) OR die('Fail Whale ' . mysqli_connect_error());

?>
```

The notice will go away with input, but I'm unsure about and the warning and the fatal error it causes.

This code works without issue on Ubuntu 14 with PHP5. I've uncommented 
extension=php_mysqli.dll
in php.ini. This is obviously a compatibility issue, but I'm unsure if I need to re-write my code or if it's a matter of a simple setting that I can't find.

Comment: Does the query return a result? Is the database exactly the same when you use PHP5 or PHP7?

Comment: Where are you including the connection file and what code preceds this? The "couldn't fetch" suggests the object `$conn` may have been closed before you attempted this `query()` call

Comment: The first notice (Trying to get property of non-object) is probably because the json_decode failed. (judging from the line position relative to the mysql errors)

Comment: Connection is included just before the rest of tLogServ

<?php include "connect.php" ?>
<?php ///code for TLogServ ?>

Databases should be the same. I created a dumpFile from one and created the other from it. Is there a way to investigate further

Answer (score 0):

The issue was two stupid mistakes.

1)The user I referenced in my connection was not given proper rights.

and

2) 'Host' was defined as the IP of the localhost. For whatever reason this worked on Cat connection, but not on WiFI (both had static Ip's).

For others with the same/similar issue. Verify that your php.ini mysqli extension is enabled/uncommmented. As A.L was onto the issue was with mySQL settings not PHP/Ubuntu.